# Timer() doesn't work with milliseconds

Tags: events, julia

I need to call a function every 0.05 seconds, but `Timer` seems to have a lowest granularity of a second:

```
Timer(function(timer)
    print("Hai!\n") # executed once a second
end, 0.05, true)
```

Is there any way to make `Timer` work with milliseconds?

Comment: Please copy your answer into the answer box instead of editing the question :)

Comment: Ai, ai, captain

Answer (score 2):

Woops, the missing type declaration somehow made me think that the third "repeat" argument is a Bool, but it's actually the time. So `true` was converted to 1. Question "solved".

Correct:

```
Timer(function(timer)
    print("Hai!\n") # executed every 0.05 seconds now
end, 0, 0.05) # callback, delay time in seconds, repeat time in seconds
```